# I'm trying to make a function (button) to upload images to my database in CodeIgniter (PHP). But I'm getting an error

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a function in CodeIgniter (PHP) so users can add images to my database but I'm getting an error when I try to upload an image..

I'm using phpMyAdmin

Database name: kadokado

Table name: products

Table row name where i want to put these images to: product_foto

image folder: upload

My controller file (Product.php):

```
    class Product extends CI_Controller { 


    var $data = array();

       public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
 }

}

     public function index()
 {
  $config = array (
   'upload_path' => 'upload/',
   'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
   'max_size' => 0,
   'filename' => url_title($this->input->post('file'))

   );
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);

   if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
    $this->db->insert('products', array(
        'product_foto' => $this->upload->product_foto
     ));
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Success');
   }

  $this->load->view('product_form', $this->data);
 }
```

}

This is my view file (product_form.php) :

```
<?php
echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
echo form_open_multipart();
echo form_upload('file');
echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
echo form_close();
?>
```

And these are the errors I'm getting:`

```
  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Upload::$product_foto

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 21

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 21
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once






A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'product_foto' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_foto`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 22
```

Comment: $config['upload_path']  = 'uploads/size/';        
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']   = '1024*20';
    $config['encrypt_name']  = true;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload('photo');   if($uploaded){                                                          $image_productimage1   = $this->upload->data();
$insert_data['size_image'] = $image_productimage1['file_name'];        
// insert data into the database                                                                       }

Comment: Try this solution this will work

Comment: You cannot use `$this->input->post('file')` to get the file name. Use `$this->upload->data('file_name'); ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
    $this->db->insert('products', array(
        'product_foto' => $this->upload->product_foto
     ));
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Success');
   }
```

to

```
 if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
    $this->db->insert('products', array(
        'product_foto' => $this->upload->data['file_name']
     ));
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Success');
   }
```

Comment: Hello! I tried you're code and for some reason I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path']      = 'uploads/size/';        
                $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_size']         = '1024*20';
                $config['encrypt_name']     = true;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $uploaded   = $this->upload->do_upload('photo');   if($uploaded){                                                          $image_productimage1         = $this->upload->data();
$insert_data['size_image']  = $image_productimage1['file_name'];        
// insert data into the database                                                                       }
```

Comment: had you checked that library is not missing     $this->load->library('upload', $config);